# Map data on runtime after post request

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-state-management

I have three apis in all. GetAssets is the first, followed by assetsOptionsList and getAssetsLibrary. The issue I'm having is that when I post the data on getAssetsLibrary, I want to be able to present it on get Assets at runtime.Everything is working fine but i want to show assets on runtime.

I'm setting the runTime state true on get request but the problem is it works only for one time.Second time, it does not map on runtime. Actually, i want to know is there any alternative so that i can achieve the goal.

In the below code the one function is getting the assets. And i want to run the one function when the post request successfully sent.

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
const [assetOptions, setAssetOptions] = useState([]);
const [faqOpened, setToggleFaq] = useState(false);
const [runTime, setRunTime] = useState(false)
const [assetID, setAssetID] = useState()
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);



const handleForm = (e) => {
    const index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    const el = e.target.childNodes[index]
    const option = el.getAttribute('id');
    setAssetID(option)

}

const formHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('media', e.target.media.files[0]);
    formData.append('assetListId', assetID)
    formData.append('name', e.target.name.value);
    console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData))


    const res = axios.post('api/asset-library',
        formData
    ).then((response) => {

        showSuccessToaster(response?.data?.message)
        setRunTime(true)
        setToggleFaq(false)
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            showErrorToaster(error?.response?.data?.message)
        })
}

const showSuccessToaster = (response) => {
    return uploadToasterSuccess.show({ message: response });
}

const showErrorToaster = (error) => {
    return uploadToasterError.show({ message: error });
}

const one = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true) 
    const data = await axios.get('api/assets').then((res) => {
        return res?.data?.data
    })
    setImages(data)
    setIsLoading(false)
}

const two = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get('/api/asset-list').then((res) => {
        return res?.data?.data
    })
    setAssetOptions(data)
}


useEffect(() => {
    one()
    two()
}, [runTime]);
```